# capybara & rspec fill_in does not fill all characters

Tags: rspec, capybara

Simple rspec test:

```
it "should login" do
   fill_in 'email', with: 'tom@domain.com'
   fill_in 'password', with: '123456'
   click_on I18n.t('ui.pages.login')

   expect(current_path).to eq('/projects')
end
```

The problem is: Chrome only enters "12456" and skips the "3" - whatever I do.

I tried the following:

1. Putting a sleep time after the email fill_in
2. Explicitly naming the email field with an ID (id="password")

no effect on both, still not all characters entered.

My setup:

- Using capybara 2.15.4
- Using rspec-core 3.7.0 Using
- chromedriver-helper 1.1.0
- Using selenium-webdriver 3.7.0

Answer (score 0):

You're probably experiencing https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1771&q=sendKeys&sort=-id&colspec=ID%20Status%20Pri%20Owner%20Summary - If you can produce a simple example that replicates the issue I'm sure the chromedriver authors would appreciate it.

Beyond that,  make sure you have updated to the most recent release of `chromedriver`.  Since you're using `chromedriver-helper` that means following these instructions - https://github.com/flavorjones/chromedriver-helper#updating-to-latest-chromedriver